# Change axes in matplotlib.pyplot.imshow while retaining aspect ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data stored in a 1000x1000 matrix that I plot using plt.imshow(), resulting in the following image:

[image]

However, the y-axis are supposed to range from 0 to 300 and the x-axis from 0 to 1. I've tried using 'extent=[0,1,0,300]', but this results in the following:

[image]

I am wondering how I can adjust the values on the axes while retaining the 1:1 aspect-ratio (this is to create a Hovmöller plot, so the y-axis is unrelated to space).

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.imshow(phi.T, extent=[0,1,0,300], origin='lower')
cbar = plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: What about keeping extent [0,1,0,300] and setting aspect to 300?

Answer (score 1):

`plt.imshow(phi.T, extent=[0,1,0,300], aspect=1/300)` should do it

Comment: Please add an explanation as to how or why your answer should resolve the question.